# Разница в видимости членов класса и обычных переменных

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, объявление

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int m = 41;
    S(int m = 42): m{m} { std::cout << m << '\n'; }
};

int main() {
    int m = 41;
    { int m = m; std::cout << m << '\n'; } // (1) not 41
    S{};                                   // (2) 42
}
```

Почему в 1 случае не используется значение `41` внешней переменной, а во втором используется внешний параметр `42`? Какие правила Стандарта определяют, что `int m = m;` и `m{m}` работают именно так?

Comment: Причем тут стандарт?  Это относится к грамматике языка

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Стандарт описывает грамматику

Answer (score 3):

Поиск имён для *инициализируемых* членов в списке инициализации конструктора не учитывает область видимости параметров конструктора.

[class.base.init / 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#2):

> mem-initializer:
>   mem-initializer-id ( expression-list<sub>opt</sub>)
>   mem-initializer-id braced-init-list
>
> Lookup for an unqualified name in a mem-initializer-id ignores the constructor's function parameter scope.

C другой стороны, поиск имён для *инициализаторов* в списке инициализации конструктора начинается в области видимости параметров конструктора.

[class.base.init / 15](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#15):

> The expression-list or braced-init-list of a mem-initializer is in the function parameter scope of the constructor and can use this to refer to the object being initialized.

```
class X {
  int a;
  int b;
  int i;
  int j;
public:
  const int& r;
  X(int i): r(a), b(i), i(i), j(this->i) { }
};
```

> initializes `X​::​r` to refer to `X​::​a`, initializes `X​::​b` with the value of the constructor parameter `i`, initializes `X​::​i` with the value of the constructor parameter `i`, and initializes `X​::​j` with the value of `X​::​i`; this takes place each time an object of class `X` is created.

Поэтому здесь

```
struct S {
    int m = 41;
    S(int m = 42): m{m} { std::cout << m << '\n'; }
};
```

член `m` структуры `S` инициализируется параметром `m` конструктора `S`.

---

Поведение конструкции

```
int m = 41;
{int m = m;}
```

описывается другим разделом стандарта языка.

[basic.scope.pdecl, Point of declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl):

> 1 The locus of a declaration ([basic.pre]) that is a declarator is immediately after the complete declarator ([dcl.decl]).
> [Example 1:
> `unsigned char x = 12;`
> `{ unsigned char x = x; }`
> Here, the initialization of the second `x` has undefined behavior, because the initializer accesses the second `x` outside its lifetime ([basic.life]). — end example]
> 2 [Note 1: A name from an outer scope remains visible up to the locus of the declaration that hides it.
> [Example 2:
> `const int  i = 2;`
> `{ int  i[i]; }`
> declares a block-scope array of two integers. — end example]
> — end note]

После того как переменная объявлена `{int m ...}`, она скрывает объявление во внешней области видимости `int m = 41;`.

Так как время жизни объекта начинается после его инициализации, то здесь

```
{int m = m;}
```

мы пытаемся прочитать значение объекта, который ещё не существует. Поведение программы не определено.

Answer (score 2):

Во втором случае `int m` в пределах блока *скрывает* переменную `int m` вне его.

В первом - это *инициализация*, так что первое `m` относится к члену-данным структуры, а второе — локальная переменная (переданная как параметр).

А вот о конкретных местах стандарта — это надо искать...

Comment: а в этом случае разве не должен был упасть пытаясь при объявлении себя себе же присвоить? `int m = m;`

Comment: если я правильно помню, то в строке ` int m = m;` просто инициализируем "неинициализированным значением" себя. Компилятор ругается, но не смертельно (так как бессмысленно).

Comment: @Grundy Нет, не должен, только вот толку с такой инициализации ноль...

Comment: @Harry, очевидно, ожидалось что у правого `m` будет значение 41, которое бы присвоилось локальной `m` - с этой стороны, толк в принципе есть.